# How to redeem credit points assigned to the customer in magento

Tags: magento, credits

I have a requirement where I want credit points to be used by the customer for future purchases. I have issued credit points to a customer account using Admin on my testing server but I cannot redeem those points using the customer account...

I have found some extensions that say they provide this functionality but I dont wanna pay for something which maybe inbuilt in magento.

Please guide, google doesn't seem to have any answers on this one...

Comment: be more verbose: magento version, what extensions are you using for this right now etc

Comment: magento 1.7 with some extensions installed like custom menu and bannerslider, which are working fine. I was able to give credit points to customer. I don't know how to redeem those as a customer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe that this is a built in feature of Magento.  I've had to do a ton of research on this - and it appears that plugins had to be made to make this possible.

One specifically that we found is: [Customer Credit Extension](http://www.mageworx.com/customer-credit-magento-extension.html)

It seems to cover everything you need to do. Good luck!